# Should I override Activerecord's update() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm refactoring my Rails 5.2 app in such a way that one model (OrigM) is being split into two (OrigM, NewM). Out in the codebase, there is code that does `update` on OrigM objects, and I want this to now result in specialized behavior in which associated OrigM and NewM objects are updated appropriately.

It seems like a straightforward way to do this is to override `update` in the OrigM model, but trying to do it a simpleminded way results in infinite recursion, because apparently even the class method `OrigM.update(id, new_attrs)` under the hood is just `find`ing the object with id `id` and calling `update` as an instance method on it.

I have figured out a couple other ways I could perhaps make this work, although I haven't fully tested them yet: (1) Update OrigM attributes by calling `write_attribute` on them individually (seems like this will not let me check validations), or (2)

```rb
self.assign_attributes(new_attrs) ## resulting in "dirty" object, then
self.save!
```

I'm leaning toward this second solution, as it seems like it ought to be pretty close to functionally identical to what the standard `update` is doing.

EDIT:
I've realized that no one can really *answer* this unless I am asking a question, so I will now recast it as:

QUESTION: Should I, or should I not, override AR's `update` method (in OrigM class)?

Commenters have said: "do not do this or you will be reviled" (which honestly I was sure someone would say lol). But... is it really such a crime? Is there a "killer" reason not to do it (something you couldn't argue with)? Or is it just a vaguely encouraged best practice?

Also: "why not just define a new method if it does something different?" Well... I guess I need to say more about the models... I don't want to try to give actual code, because it's too complex. Suffice to say: most of the code still interacts with OrigM objects, and will not know about NewM. NewM was only needed architecturally because I needed to allow multiple OrigMs to share (belong_to) a single NewM to avoid duplication of data. So I would like to allow most of the rest of the code to maintain the illusion that there is still only OrigM, and be able to update it as usual. This feels like the most elegant solution to me. If I create a new `OrigM#myupdate`, future developers (including myself) might curse me because they tried to do a simple `update` and it broke things. Iow, isn't having to know that there is a special updating function just as confusing as having to know that AR's update has been overridden?

Comment: Please don't overide the `update` method in AR. That is a terrible idea and all future developers will curse your name and ancestors.
Try looking at [Nested Attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) Or Modifying the method that updates OrigM to be two different methods that updates both the Original and New models.

Can you give us some examples of the data / columns that are being separated, and the methods that are updating the models? This will help give direction as to the purpose of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, I don't think I fully understand you, I don't get why you want to override update and not just define another method if it actually does something different. Can you show the actual code you want to refactor?